# Catalina folders handling with two different users

Tags: java, tomcat, war, tomcat8

I have two users in a Linux environment.
Let's say: **prod** and **run**. They have different responsibilities.

**prod** installs a java war based application with an external Tomcat. And it also updates this application. Installation and update use same script. This script responsibilities here:

- If there is a Tomcat already - the process removes it.
- Copies the selected Tomcat to the right place
- etc etc.

**run** starts Tomcat and the application.

Use case:

- I installed the application with **prod**
- Then, started the application with **run** - When I did this, work/Catalina and other Catalina subdirectories were created. The owner of these folders is the **run** user. (it is important information for the problem)
- Stop the application with **run**
- I tried to use update script with **prod** user but I got errors because this user didn't have permission to delete Catalina folders.

This is the infos of a Catalina folder:

```
drwxr-x---. 3 **run** groupOwner 23 Jun 13 11:55 Catalina
```

How can I change the write permission of the Catalina folder to Group level at the creation time of this?
Is there any configuration for it, for example in server.xml? At the Service or Engine tags?

Or how can I trigger Tomcat (not start) for creating the Catalina folders during installation? With this process, the owner of the Catalina folder would be the **prod** and it could remove it.

Comment: Far as I know, there are no such configuration to create folders with different user in Tomcat, server.xml or otherwise. What you could try is after the Tomcat starts issue chmod at the end of the script and change the permissions, that probably would work.